# Mysql atomical id increment

Tags: mysql

I want to create a revision control system and the query for a new entry with revision nr 1 would be like this:

The id and revision number combined are the primary key.

```
insert into contentfile (id, name, revision, active) 
values ((select max(id) +1 from contentfile), 'name', 1, 1)
```

Will this be atomical enough or is it possible that the generated id with the subquery will concurrently be chosen by another invokation of this query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to re-invent something that already exists. Modify your table by adding the autoincrement option to the `id` field, then insert your records like this:

```
INSERT INTO contentfile(name, revision, active) VALUES('name', 1, 1);
```

The id will be automatically incremented by the MySQL server. All id values will be unique.

Comment: Yes but I want the id and revision number together to be unique not only the id.